# Help with installing latest version of MongoDB on raspberry pi 4

Tags: mongodb

I can't seem to install the latest version of mongoDB on Raspberry pi 4.
I have tried doing

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb
```

This installs mongoDB 2.4.

Comment: I thought MongoDB needed a 64-bit OS. The current Raspbian version is 32-bit. So you either need to try with the Gentoo64 OS, try with the experimental Raspbian 64 kernel or try installing an old 32-bit version of Mongo.

Comment: You have already installed MongoDB https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/103781/79866 and you wrote here again "*This installs mongoDB 2.4*". So what's the question? Do you want another version?

Comment: Just now I tried your command to install mongodb.  A couple of minutes later, I got the message "Processing triggers for systemd (241 ...), then *** Error: Timeout was reached ***.  Are you asking how to solve the timeout problem?

Comment: no, it installs fine however when I go to run my node.js app it then creates an error which says that the version of mongodb installed is not up to date and doesn't work with the node mongo drivers

Comment: I have tried the Raspian Buster 64 Kernel and the same has happened.

Answer (score 0):

You need a 64-bit OS to install the latest version of MongoDB on a Raspberry Pi.

Since the Pi platform is not officially supported anymore by MongoDB, you can compile from source by yourself by following these detailed instructions, or download the unofficial binaries I have created: https://github.com/themattman/mongodb-raspberrypi-binaries

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-server
```

Comment: Please explain why do you believe that this will install the latest version of MongoDB and not version 2.4.14 as given in the default Raspbian repository.